How to avoid having to use client secrets in local development for confidential client applications
Given a AspNetCore WebApi application with a corresponding App Registration running in Kubernetes with an assigned Workload Identity.
Given that the application must call MSGraph with application permissions, that is, it needs to request an access token for downstream API calls in its own name (i.e. not per user delegation).
Given the following configuration
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration, configSectionName: "AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

  "AzureAd": {
    "TenantId": "<tenantId>",
    "ClientId": "<clientId>",
    "ClientCredentials": [
      {
        "SourceType": "SignedAssertionFilePath"
      }
    ]
  },

Then this works perfectly fine when the application is running inside the Kubernetes cluster, but obviously not at all wenn running localy. How could it, there is no signed assertion file.
I want to configure an additional/alternative client credential source for local development. But apart from ClientSecret non of the CredentialSources seem suitable. As the whole point of using Workload Identity federation was to avoid having to handle ClientSecrets I reluctant to re-introduce them just for local development.
I had expected something like with Azure.Identity where the DefaultAzureCredential is able to fallback onto developer specific authentication like AzureCliCredential or VisualStudioCredential.
Is this possible?

I did a bit of a deep dive into the source code of microsoft-identity-web and discovered that the the SignedAssertionFromManagedIdentityCredentialLoader in fact uses DefaultAzureCredential, but with most fallbacks disabled.

See ManagedIdentityClientAssertion and SignedAssertionFromManagedIdentityCredentialLoader

Based on those I tried implementing my own custom ICrendentialSourceLoader with AzureCliCredential and InteractiveBrowserCredential activated but that failed with

AADSTS700019: Application ID fb60f99c-7a34-4190-8149-302f77469936 cannot be used or is not authorized.

The referenced application Id seems to belong to api://AzureADTokenExchange
I also found issue #2644 where it seems to be implied that this will never work. Although I do not understand why.

[...] when debugging locally, [DefaultAzureCredential] will fall back to attempting to obtain a token for the api://AzureADTokenExchange resource using Azure CLI (with an AzureCliCredential), which is guaranteed to fail. [...]


Just a note, the docs do directly call out the need for a certificate/secret when working locally: "You can only use managed identities, however, for software workloads running in Azure. For a software workload running outside of Azure, you need to use application credentials (a secret or certificate) to access Microsoft Entra protected resources (such as Azure, Microsoft Graph, Microsoft 365, or third-party resources)." (source)

+1 because I hope someone has a better solution, but it seems to be working as-intended (no easy way to use managed identities in a local environment).

Does changing your source type to "SourceType": "DefaultAzureCredential"  in your Startup.cs file (having made sure that you import Azure.Identity, previously installed with dotnet add package Azure.Identity) not do the trick for you?

@anmabe Azure.Identity is already a transitive dependency. And the use of "Developer"-Credentials seems to be intentionally deactivated. See the ManagedIdentityClientAssertion.cs file I linked above.
